# A problem on PIN

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Matthias does not exactly remember the four-digit PIN on his tablet,
but he does remember that the secret number is divisible by $2$, by $3$, by $5$, by $7$, and by $11$.
Can you suggest a possible combination for him?

### First question.

If the secret number must be divisible by $2, 3, 5, 7$ and $11$, then it must be the least common multiple (lcm) of these numbers.

The **lcm** of $2, 3, 5, 7$ and $11$ is $2310$.

Therefore, a possible combination could be $2310$.

### Second question.

> How many tries, max,
> will Mattia have to make to get the PIN right?

How do I find the answer without using combinatorial calculus since this question is included in a high school first-year book?

The solutions on my book are, $2310$
and $4$
attempts.

Comment: Well, How many multiples of $2310$ have four digits?  Note that your statement "If the secret number must be divisible by 2,3,5,7
 and 11
, then it must be the least common multiple (lcm) of these numbers." is false.  Any multiple of $2310$ works as well.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much.  The solutions on my book are, $2310$ and $4$ Attempts

Comment: Why there is a negative vote?

Comment: Isn't $0000$ also valid?

Comment: @JMP Why $0000$ is it valid?

Comment: @lulu I have not understood your comment. Sorry.

Comment: What is it you don't understand about my comment?

Comment: @lulu it may be because I am not an English speaker but I don't understand how to find the second answer. Why do you write "How many multiples of 2310
 have four digits?" an why If the secret number must be divisible by 2,3,5,7 and 11 , then it must be the least common multiple (lcm) of these numbers?

Comment: Well, what you are claiming is obviously false.  It is not true that the only number divisible by $a,b$ is the least common multiple of $a,b$.  For instance, with $a=2, b=3$ we have $6,12,18, 24, 30, \cdots$ all divisible by the lcm, which is $6$.  In your case, the lcm is $2310$, so the pin could be that, or it could be $4620$ or $6930$ and so on.  And, as others have remarked, $0000$ would also appear to work (as $0$ is certainly divisible by $2,3,5,7,11$).

Comment: @lulu Now I have understand. MIlle grazie.